# keyerror : word ' ' not in vocabulary WORD2VEC

Tags: python, word2vec, keyerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j25Yb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfMMM.png)i'm working on Python Project and i'm using Word2Vec to recommend products.
The code works absolutely fine for the data set containing 19401, but whenever i pass the id of the product i get **this error "keyerror : word '1077' not in vocabulary "** I don't know how to fix this problem since i have very little knowledge about it,,I am still learning.Please help me fix this problem!

purchases_train = []

```
for i in tqdm(product_train):
    temp = train_df[train_df["Clothing ID"] == i]["Review Text"].tolist()
    purchases_train.append(temp)


purchases_val = []

for i in tqdm(validation_df['Clothing ID'].unique()):
    temp = validation_df[validation_df["Clothing ID"] == i]["Review Text"].tolist()
    purchases_val.append(temp)



model = Word2Vec(window = 10, sg = 1, hs = 0,
                 negative = 10, # for negative sampling
                 alpha=0.03, min_count= 1 , min_alpha=0.0007,
                 seed = 14)


model.build_vocab(purchases_train, progress_per=200)
model.train(purchases_train, total_examples = model.corpus_count, 
            epochs=10, report_delay=1)

# save word2vec model
model.save("word2vec_2.model")


model.init_sims(replace=True)

# extract all vectors
X = model[model.wv.vocab]

products = train_df[["Clothing ID", "Review Text"]]

# remove duplicates
products.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, subset='Clothing ID', keep="last")

# create product-ID and product-description dictionary
products_dict = products.groupby('Clothing ID')['Review Text'].apply(list).to_dict()


def similar_products(v, n = 6):
    
    # extract most similar products for the input vector
    ms = model.similar_by_vector(v, topn= n+1)[1:]
    
    # extract name and similarity score of the similar products
    new_ms = []
    for j in ms:
        pair = (products_dict[j[0]][0], j[1])
        new_ms.append(pair)
        
    return new_ms


similar_products(model['1077'])
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback of the error, along with sample data you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error, `word '847' not in vocabulary`, then you can be sure: the token `'847'` was not provided in your training data.

If you thought it was there, you should look over the data to see that it's not.

If your code needs to be able to do something useful for words not in the training data, you should extend it to either:

(1) check if a word is present before attempting to get its vector

```
    if '847' in model:
        similar_products(model['847'])
    else:
        # do something else
        ...
```

...or...

(2) catch the `KeyError` & do something else when it's caught.